# numpy.ndindex and array slices

Tags: python, numpy

I have a multidimensional array, in which I want to get `1D` slices, something like `mega_array[:, i, j, k, .....]`

To do it, I try `numpy.ndindex:`

```
for idx in np.ndindex(mega_array.shape[1:]):
    print mega_array[:, index]
```

But alas: this still gives me multidimensional slices, where only the dimension, other than first, are equal to one.

I want to use the slices as l-value, so, simple ravel() is not suitable here.

What should I use to get normal, 1D slices?

---

UPD: Here's a small example:

```
in_array = np.asarray([[7, 40], [777, 440]])
    for index in np.ndindex(in_array.shape[1:]):
        print "---"
    print index
    print in_array[:, index] # gives 2D array
```

UPD: Here's a 3D example:

```
in_array = np.asarray([[[7, 40, 5], [777, 440, 0]], [[8, 41, 6], [778, 441, 1]]])
print in_array
print in_array.shape
# print in_array[:, 0, 2]
for index in np.ndindex(in_array.shape[1:]):
    print index
    print in_array[:, index]  # FAILS

# expected [7, 8], [40, 41], [5, 6], [778, 441] and so on.
```

Comment: So what you mean by 1D slice? do you want a row? can you add an example?

Comment: Yes, I want to get a row.

Comment: So whats wrong with simple indexing? `in_array[0]` will give you the first row

Comment: I've added an example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add a `slice` to the `index`.

In:

```
in_array = np.asarray([[7, 40], [777, 440]])
for index in np.ndindex(in_array.shape[1:]):
    print "---"
    print index
    print in_array[:, index] # gives 2D array
```

`index` has values like `(0,)`,`(1,)`, i.e. tuples.

`in_array[:,(1,)]` is not the same as `in_array[:,1]`.  To get the latter you need to use `in_array[(slice(None),1)]`.  The `slice` must be part of the index tuple.  We can do that by concatenating tuples.

```
in_array = np.asarray([[7, 40], [777, 440]])
for index in np.ndindex(in_array.shape[1:]):
    print "---"
    index = (slice(None),)+index
    print index
    print in_array[index]
```

printing:

```
---
(slice(None, None, None), 0)
[  7 777]
---
(slice(None, None, None), 1)
[ 40 440]
```

Same adjustment should work with the nD array case

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`np.dstack`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dstack.html#numpy.dstack) that stack arrays in sequence depth wise (along third axis). :

```
>>> a
array([[[  7,  40,   5],
        [777, 440,   0]],

       [[  8,  41,   6],
        [778, 441,   1]]])
>>> np.dstack(a)
array([[[  7,   8],
        [ 40,  41],
        [  5,   6]],

       [[777, 778],
        [440, 441],
        [  0,   1]]])
```

Also based on your dimensions you can use other numpy joining functions :http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.array-manipulation.html#joining-arrays

Comment: I have a problem: not always I have only 2D arrays. In case of 3D on N-d ones I cannot just give it an integer. And I don't know exactly the max number of dimensions.

Comment: @Felix can you add a 3D example?

Comment: I've just added a 3D example.

Comment: @Felix Thanks can you pls add your expected output too!

Comment: I've added them. Maybe the order of output may be incorrect, but just now it fails at all.

Answer (score 0):

do you need to [transpose](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.transpose.html) the matrix to get the rows?

```
In [5]: in_array = numpy.asarray([[7, 40], [777, 440]])
In [6]: in_array.transpose()[0]
Out[6]: array([  7, 777])
```

Comment: Sometimes I have 3D arrays or N-d ones. Here the trick doesn't work.

Comment: Could you elaborate on your examples to show what you exactly want to get from an 2D array and from a 3D array? Thx

Comment: Just added a 3D example.

Comment: Let's focus on what you want to get. I don't understand the last item in your example: `[778, 441]` I would expect the sequence to continue as: `[7, 8], [40, 41], [5, 6], [7, 778], [40, 441], [5, 1], [777, 8], [440, 41], [0, 6], [777, 778], [440, 441], [0,1]`. Could you please finish your expected sequence?

Answer (score 0):

After you posted your 3D example, now I see what you wish to do. The following should work for arrays with more than 3 dimensions, too:

Save the number of items in the dimensions > 0,

```
nitems = np.product(in_array.shape[1:])
```

Reshape the array (similar to np.dstack pointed out by Kasra),

```
new_array = np.reshape(in_array, [in_array.shape[0], nitems])
```

Loop over new array:

```
for i in range(new_array.shape[1]):
    print(new_array[:, i])
```

For me, that gives the expected output.